# Hikvision SDK on ARM

Tags: linux, gcc, sdk, arm, hikvision

I need to change parameters of my HikVision camera on a OrangePI board. After realizing that using OnVif need a lot of works, tried to use [their SDK](http://www.hikvision.com/en/download_83.html) (linux 32-bit). After downloading that file as mentioned in readme files copied the lib files into `consoleDemo/linux32/lib` directory and `consoleDemo/linux32/make`, but receiving following errors:

```
g++ -L ../lib/  -o ../lib/sdkTest Voice.o consoleMain.o playback.o tool.o CapPicture.o Alarm.o GetStream.o ConfigParams.o -I../../src/  -I../../include/ -Wl,-rpath=./:./HCNetSDKCom:../lib -lhcnetsdk
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../lib//libhcnetsdk.so when searching for -lhcnetsdk
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhcnetsdk
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:27: recipe for target '../lib/sdkTest' failed
make: *** [../lib/sdkTest] Error 1
```

I've also make on an ubuntu system as thought there might be for x86 systems not ARM, but no success, same error.

Comment: Did you ask them ?

Comment: They don't have a forum like section and about support section I don't think get even an answer (tried before).

Comment: Your reseller should help !

Comment: Are you compiling or cross-compiling ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, No, directly compiling.

Comment: The message indicates that the library is not of the good type. 32/64 bits or processor confusion.

Comment: I'm afraid that one but suspected, so is there any work around? Should be better to stick to OnVif?